# Is the Loi Lamine Gueye- law n ° 46-940 of May 7, 1946 enacted by the French Parliament active even today?

Tags: france, international-relations, french-empire

How many countries(former French colonies) have annulled this? And, has this been annulled by France as well after the dissolution of French Union?

Comment: I think this is mostly a question for law.stackexchange.com. That said, you could add some context (like explaining what the law is about).